# Slow serial communication with arduino? Latency of almost 1 sec?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

Just trying some things out, as I want to use my Arduino Nano as an interface to my computer with a couple of LED's and buttons. So I need to send some commands and data to the Arduino from my PC. However i find the serial communication of the Arduino quite slow. In fact, from the moment I press Enter to send, my command in the Serial Monitor takes almost a second to execute (in this case to control an LED).

Is this a limitation or can it be sped up somehow?

Here's my simple code:

```
String cmd;
int loopNum;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

if(loopNum == 0) {
Serial.println("Waiting for commands"); // Only display this when sketch is initiated. 
}

cmd = Serial.readString();

if(cmd == "LEDON") {
digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
Serial.println("LED ON");
}
if(cmd == "LEDOFF") {
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
Serial.println("LED OFF");
}
if(cmd == "HELP") {
Serial.println("Available commands:\nLEDON\nLEDOFF\nHelp");
}

loopNum++; // Counts the loop...
delay(50);
}
```

Changing the  baud rate of the serial doesn't seem to change anything.

Some help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: You are not checking if there's anything to read when you call Serial.readString().  You discovered that the default for Serial.setTimeout() is 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solution was to set:

```
Serial.setTimeout(50);
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, to improve your program, you have to modify your code as:

```
String cmd;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("Waiting for commands"); // Only display this when sketch is initiated. 
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        cmd = Serial.readString(); //Assign cmd just if someone send string in serial monitor

        if(cmd == "LEDON") {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            Serial.println("LED ON");
        }
        if(cmd == "LEDOFF") {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            Serial.println("LED OFF");
        }
        if(cmd == "HELP") {
            Serial.println("Available commands:\nLEDON\nLEDOFF\nHelp");
        } 
    } //Serial.available()
}
```

I suppose that you don't need to count the loop (there's no reason why you have to do it, improving delay). 
Using [Serial.available()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available) function help you to check if statements just if someone is send a string in the serial monitor (reducing your delay).
At last, to print something just one time in your program, you could put it into the [Setup()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Setup) function.

Answer (score -2):

When you send a string from the serial monitor, it sends all the strings one by one. So if you send 'LEDON' it will transfer 5 characters one by one serially. Thats why it takes some time in execution.

Comment: Even more, it will transfer each character (which is composed by 8 bits) one bit at a time! And it even adds 2 control bits (start and stop), so it requires 50 clock cycles to transfer it! But... wait... It's how serial communications work! 50 cycles at 9600 bit/s means about 5 ms. The reason here is obviously not the fact that the serial communication sends data serially...